# Approve and Delete option when selecting rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi all I created a table with list of items.When I swipe the particular row,the option will open up with ***Approve*** and ***Delete*** which display at the bottom of the table.

Issue :

On clicking the Approve. It select all the row and not  to the particular row to apply. The same issue I m facing in the Delete option as well.

Here is my [Code](http://pastie.org/9002637)

How to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `selector` is wrong. Replace this code at line number 133 in [code](http://pastie.org/9002637#1),

```
var selectedRow = $(e.target).closest('tr');
```

instead of,

```
var selectedRow=$(this);
```

<kbd>**[SEE THIS DEMO](http://jsbin.com/tafudube/1/)**</kbd>